# Add a parameter into kwargs during function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

Is there a way to add key-value-pair into kwargs during the function call?

```
def f(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

# ...

pre_defined_kwargs = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

f(**pre_defined_kwargs, c=3)
```

Or even change the existing arguments?

```
f(**pre_defined_kwargs, b=3)  # replaces the earlier b=2
```

These two examples don't work, as they raise error

```
>>> f(**pre_defined_kwargs, c=3)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Pointing at the comma in between the arguments

Comment: put `c=3` first? `f(c=3,**pre_defined_kw)`

Comment: why would you replace the b and not just use  `**pre_defined_kw` or change `pre_defined_kwargs`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For Python versions < 3.5, you need to place the `**kwargs` variable keyword argument *last*:

```
f(c=3, **pre_defined_kwargs)
```

See the [*Calls* expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#calls); in all forms of the grammar the `"**" expression` rule is placed *last*. In other words, using anything after the `**expression` syntax is a syntax error.

If you want to update the dictionary with new values, you can use the [`dict()` callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict); it can create a copy of your existing dictionary *and* update keys in that, provided the keys are also valid Python identifiers (start with a letter or underscore, and only contain letters, digits and underscores):

```
f(c=3, **dict(pre_defined_kwargs, b=42))
```

Here `b=42` sets a *new* value for the `'b'` key. This same syntax can be used to add keys too, of course.

You cannot use the same key both in the `**expression` mapping and explicitly; that'll raise a `TypeError`. Again, from the documentation already linked:

> If the syntax `**expression` appears in the function call, `expression` must evaluate to a mapping, the contents of which are treated as additional keyword arguments. In the case of a keyword appearing in both `expression` and as an explicit keyword argument, a `TypeError` exception is raised.

Demo:

```
>>> def f(**kwargs):
...     print(kwargs)
... 
>>> pre_defined_kwargs = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> f(c=3, **pre_defined_kwargs)
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> dict(pre_defined_kwargs, b=42)
{'a': 1, 'b': 42}
>>> f(c=3, **dict(pre_defined_kwargs, b=42))
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 42}
```

This restriction has been lifted as of Python 3.5 (thanks to [PEP-448 -- *Additional Unpacking Generalizations*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/); you can now freely mix the order of argument types and use multiple `**mapping` references in a call (using distinct mappings). Keywords still have to be unique across all arguments applied; you still can't 'override' arguments that appear more than once.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> f(c=3, **pre_defined_kwargs)
{'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen, try `f(**dict(pre_defined_kwargs, b=22))`.